# angular js select default value not working

Tags: angularjs

I am having problem with setting default for my select list. Any help on this would be appreciated. I looked at the other similar posts but the solutions are not seem to be working in my case.

I populate $scope.series in the controller. and then the drop down seems to be populating as well but it is not setting the default value.

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect"
                            ng-init="selectedItem = series[0].code"
                            ng-model="selectedItem"
                            ng-options="serie.name for serie in series track by serie.code"
                            ng-change="update()"></select>
```

here is the json:

```
[
    {
        "code": "code1",
        "name": "name 1",
    },
    {
        "code": "code2",
        "name": "name 2",
    }
]
```

Following is the controller

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller('myController', function ($scope, dataService) {
    dataService.getSeries(function (response) {
        $scope.series = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
    })});
```

Where dataService is the service to get json file from $http get.

Comment: This is considered [bad practice to use ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) this way. Just set the value in the controller. This might also fix your issue.

Comment: BTW, also don't initialize the selectedItem to series[0].code, but to series[0], since that's what the ng-model contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had `ng-init` which tries to evaluate expression when there was no value in `series`, because the ajax for it doesn't return the value yet.

So you need to set the `ng-model` value in ajax success instead of `ng-init`

**Markup**

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect"
   ng-model="selectedItem"
   ng-options="serie.name for serie in series"
   ng-change="update()">
</select>
```

**Code**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller('myController', function ($scope, dataService) {
    dataService.getSeries(function (response) {
        $scope.series = response.data;
        $scope.selectedItem = $scope.series[0].code; //setting ng-model after getting data
        console.log(response.data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like adding this code to controller did the trick and no need to have ng-init as well.:

```
$scope.selectedItem = { code: $scope.series[0].code, name: $scope.series.name };
```